# Benefits of deploying kubernetes in juju vs deploy it directly in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, juju

Can anyone tell me what are the benefits of using KUBERNETES_PROVIDER as juju instead of ubuntu and what are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

The juju provider makes it easier to scale and integrate other elements over time.

Comment: But when we use kubernetes, is it not his task to do that?

Comment: Ah, two different levels. Your sysadmins / operators can use Juju to stand up Kubernetes on bare metal, public cloud, openstack or vmware. And then your devops talk to the Kubernetes API to deploy their containers. Yes, Kubernetes will dynamically allocate *containers*, but Juju models the Kubernetes apps themselves at the lower level. Make sense?